# gradle DRY approach for multip project jar manifast value

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have subproject under widgets

```
 widgets
     widget1
     widget2
     widget3
     etc
```

I need to add

```
   jar 
      { 
        manifest
           { 
               attributes  'widget-name': widgetName 
               attributes  'widget-description': widgetDescription
               attributes  'widget-args': widgetArgs
               ...
           }
      }
```

In all the subproject and add distinct names to each project

I dont want to write this in each project (':widgets:widget1') { jar {...}}

How can i use DRY in this build file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
subprojects {
    jar { 
        manifest { 
            attributes 'widget-name': project.name 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops sorry i do have other hardcoaded values also :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It may not be worth to factor out this code.

Comment: I have multiple widget subproject.  and each project going to have same set of  jar.manifest.attributes ...  same keys and differnt values. So we need to create individual project(':widgets:widget[X]') blocks and add same code ?

Comment: Or use regular coding techniques to factor out the code. Maintaining the data mapping won't be much easier though. Instead of individual `project(':widgets:widget[X]')` blocks, I'd typically use a separate build script per subproject.

Comment: Yes. That is the worst case :).  i tried to write a method and return the  jar once and later tried to return manifest but both time gradle is not recognized. So i need to go with individual build file then.